# How to add multiple buttons in accessory view of UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to add two adjacent custom buttons in the UITableView's accessory view.

I tried doing `cell.accessoryView = customButton;` and then 
`cell.accessoryView = customButton2` .It is obvious that this replaces the previous button.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a UIView containing the two buttons as a custom accessoryView.

```
UIView *buttonsView = [...];
// add buttons to buttonsView
cell.accessoryView = buttonsView;
```

Or you can subclass UITableViewCell and add two buttons there.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        UIButton *buttonA = ....
        UIButton *buttonB = ....
        [self.contentView addSubview:buttonA];
        [self.contentView addSubview:buttonB];
    }

    return self;
}
```

If you haven't done a custom UITableViewCell before this article might help.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom UIView class with your buttons placed inside of it (as subviews: `[self addSubview:button]`). Then you can assign your custom UIView object as accessoryView of a cell.

`cell.accessoryView = yourCustomView;`